# search a text in a file and return the string as variable

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scripting

i have a file which contains list of path with file names and i need to search these paths in a other file and if it matches it should be return as a variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (D:\newfolder\1.txt) do (
set line=%%a
set chars=!line:~7!
echo !chars:~0! >> D:\automation\2.txt
echo !chars:~0!
echo Find  "!chars:~0!" D:\newfolder\lastlines.txt >>3.txt
echo Find  "!chars:~0!" D:\newfolder\lastlines.txt 
Find  "!chars:~0!" D:\newfolder\lastlines.txt 
  )
if %errorlevel% equ 1 ( goto notfound
echo set file = "!chars:~0!"
:notfound


 1.txt 
test.xml
new\db\new.sql
new\old\test.sql
old\web\test.js


2.txt

                         [exec]   E:\source\testing\ui\r.aspx(212): warning JS1204: Not all required arguments have been supplied [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec]   E:\source\testing\ui\r.aspx(213): warning JS1187: Variable '' might not be initialized [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec]   E:\source\testing\ui\n.aspx(14): warning JS1204: Not all required arguments have been supplied [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec]   E:\source\testing\ui\n.aspx(112): warning JS1204: Not all required arguments have been supplied [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec]   E:\source\testing\ui\n.aspx(127): warning JS1204: Not all required arguments have been supplied [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec]   E:\source\testing\ui\n.aspx(185): warning JS1204: Not all required arguments have been supplied [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec]   E:\source\testing\ui\n.aspx(213): warning JS1204: Not all required arguments have been supplied [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec]   E:\source\testing\ui\n.aspx(237): warning JS1204: Not all required arguments have been supplied [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec]   e:\source\testing\ui\P.aspx.cs(25): warning CS0414: The field '' is assigned but its value is never used [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec] 
                         [exec] 
                         [exec] "E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj" (default target) (1) ->
                         [exec] (AspNetCompiler target) -> 
                         [exec]   E:\source\testing\old\web\test.js(8): error : Variable '' has not been declared [E:\source\testing\old\web\v.wdproj]
                         [exec] 
                         [exec]     1 Error(s)
                         [exec]
```

here i am not able to retrive the matched line (new\db\test.sql) and it returns the last line present in 1.txt file.

Thanks,

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to solve a problem stated as ""my code doesn't do what I want it to do" without an example of desired outcome. There doesn't seem to be any purpose in uing `~7` for example - what are you trying to match against what returning what?

Comment: actually 1.txt file has 7 white spaces and followed by the path, so i have used ~7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way we could have worked out that your data had 7 leading spaces - you need to specify such matters.

It's still not clear what you want as output, but

1. !chars:~0! is identical to !chars!
2. "tokens=*" will suppress leading spaces on the value assigned to the metavariable `%%a` whereas "delims=" will retain them.

Hence, setting chars to all-but-the-first-seven characters of the line will lop off the first 7 **AFTER** the leading spaces have been removed.

Comment: Thats Ok for me, i will work on that, but i am not able to retrieve the actual result using find (may last lines of code..)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FINDSTR /L /b /e /g:2.txt 1.txt 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET "file=") ELSE (FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (2.txt) DO SET file=%%a)
ECHO file=%file%
GOTO :EOF
```

If you mean to set a variable if the single line in `2.txt` also appears in `1.txt` then the above should work. The variable `file` will be set if the line matches a line in `1.txt` and empty if not.

---

Revision

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "file="
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (1.txt) DO IF NOT DEFINED file (
 ECHO %%a|FINDSTR /L /i /b /e /g:2.txt >nul
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET file=%%a)
)
ECHO file=%file%
GOTO :EOF
```

Hmm - yes, I'd forgotten that `1.txt` has leading spaces. Let's try this one...

---

My test data files
1.txt

```
       test.xml
       new\db\new.sql
       new\old\test.sql
       old\web\test.js
```

2.txt

```
new\db\new.sql
```

result:

```
file=new\db\new.sql
```

I've tried changing 2.txt by removing the final `l` and by appending an extra `z` after that final `l`. Both yielded `file=` as a result.

I could break it by appending spaces before or after the text in `2.txt`.

In order to run directly from the prompt, you'd need to reduce each `%%` to `%` else you'll get the message you report.

---

Edit : final revision given new test data

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "file="
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (1.txt) DO IF NOT DEFINED file (
 FINDSTR /L /i "%%a" 2.txt >nul
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET file=%%a)
)
ECHO file=%file%
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows empty output. echo file is showing blank

Comment: but the line exists and all the text in 2.txt is in the form of paragraph

Comment: it's not working but when i have ran this code line by line it is showing %%a was unexpected at this time, i could see the errorlevel also not changed but the result is showing blank

Comment: thanks, it worked but in the 2.txt file i have modified the text in a big paragraph and now the "new\db\new.sql" has been appended by few extra path like "D:\test\new\db\new.sql" for this this script is not working ... may be a small change is required..

Comment: Would have to see the data. You can edit your original post by clicking on `EDIT` below the tags. You'd need to include any notes like '1.txt has 7 leading spaces on each line` as is relevant. Spaces are a little hard to see if they are at the end of lines...

Comment: Hi, please find my updated 2.txt where i need to find the strings present in 1.txt "old\web\test.js" as 2.txt contains with appended path